# How to handle event when option is selected?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to handle event when current option is selected. I have a custom option component:

[image]

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
    props.isFocused ? dispatch(getPatientData(props.data.patient)) : null; // dispatch doesn't work, unless sync code, like console.log()
  }, [props.isFocused]);
```

there is isFocused prop, but dispatch doesn't work.

Comment: FYI there's absolutely no need to disable the lint rule; you're in a block body, write a regular `if` condition.

Comment: if getPatientData function is an async function then you can return a Promise from it and then you can dispatch

Comment: incomplete dependencies, Currently you don't let ```useEffect``` to trigger in proper condition.

Comment: Kaneki21, getPatientData is a redux action. I ve tried to call dispatch in promise, but that didn't help(

Comment: Vahid Alimohamadi, what's wrong here in your opinion?

Comment: @Kaneki21 getPatientData is a redux action. I ve tried to call dispatch in promise, but that didn't help(

Comment: try some console.log in the action. if you share the slice code then may be we could help better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.